# Tedious four variable equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to calculate something very tedious. I got this after calculating a Lagrangian equation with three multipliers. I need to write each of $k_x, k_y, l_x, l_y$ in terms of $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{l}$.

\begin{align}
k_yl_x = 16k_xl_y \tag{1}\\
k_x + k_y = 50 \tag{2} \\
l_x + l_y = \overline{l} \tag{3}\\
k_x^{0.2} l_x^{0.8} = \overline{x} \tag{4}
\end{align}

One way is certainly to force variables in terms of other variables and compute using R. But I am looking for a manual approach.

Comment: You can eliminate $k_y$ and $l_y$ using (2) and (3), then you can eliminate either $l_x$ or $k_x$ using (1), then you can eliminate the remaining variable using (4). So it might be tedious but it's not really clear what to say to answer your question, except writing out some rearrangements of the equations.

Comment: What was the original equation system?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel no equation system. It's an optimization problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $k_y=50-k_x$ and $l_y=\bar l-l_x$ then
$$(50-k_x)l_x=16k_x(\bar l-l_x)$$ gives us
$$
15k_xl_x+50l_x=16k_x\bar l
$$
so
$$
l_x={16k_x\bar l\over15 k_x+50}
$$
now we have
$$
k_x^{0.2}\left({16k_x \bar l\over15k_x+50}\right)^{0.8}=\bar x
$$
I suppose this is
$$
{16k_x^{5/4}\over 15k_x+50}={\bar x^{5/4}\over \bar l}
$$
There probably isn't any simple algebraic way to rearrange that into the form $k_x=$ so you probably would have to solve that last equation numerically for $k_x$.

.